# ColdFusion 10 SOLR install

Tags: solr, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am running Coldfusion 10 (10,0,9,284568) on Win7 64bit developer instance.  Initially we had no need for SOLR, so we did not include it in the original ColdFusion install.  However, we now have need, so I downloaded ColdFusion_10_Jetty_Solr_win.exe from adobe, and installed using default values, and received no errors.  However, when I open CF Admin to add a collection, I receive the cannot create collection error.

What is the SOLR home directory supposed to be set to in ColdFusion Admin?  I tried several values, (`coldfusionjetty\solr`, and `coldfusionjetty\multicore\`), and they all appear to work. But when I go to create a collection  I always receive the cannot create error.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled the ColdFusion 10 SOLR multiple times, but no improvement.  Adobe has no documentation on this that I can find.  Any ideas?

**Edit:**

--- nevermind, I was finally able to get it to work.  For anyone else who wonders where the Coldfusion SOLR Home should be, I set the SOLR host to `localhost` and the SOLR home to `C:/ColdFusionJetty/multicore/` using CF admin, saved, then created a collection and it worked.  I swear I tried the multicore directory earlier, but perhaps not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Glad you were able to solve the problem. You should post the solution as an "answer" and accept it. (FYI, you may have to wait a few hours to accept given your new member status).

Answer (score 0):

> For anyone else who wonders where the Coldfusion SOLR Home should be, I set the SOLR host to localhost and the SOLR home to C:/ColdFusionJetty/multicore/ using CF admin, saved, then created a collection and it worked. I swear I tried the multicore directory earlier, but perhaps not.

**References**

- [Jetspeed Deployers Guide - Apache Tomcat Overview](https://portals.apache.org/jetspeed-2/deployguide/guide-tomcat.html)
- [Solr Tomcat](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat)
- [Apache Tomcat 7 (7.0.78) - Security Considerations](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html)
- [Solr Wiki: Why no WAR](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/WhyNoWar)